# VB.NET No Such host is known IP Grabber

Tags: windows, vb.net

My program grabs the IP of specific subdomains of a host. If one of them don't exist it gives an error saying: No Such Host Is Known. How can i make it replace the text in lblDirect to "Not Found" instead of give an error.

```
Dim dHostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("direct." + TextBox1.Text)
Dim dip As IPAddress() = dHostname.AddressList
lblDirect.Text = dip(0).ToString
```

Is the code i'm using for grabbing the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Try...Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to handle error and set your label value in the **catch** section.